# semantic-ui multiselect dropdown selects item when clicking out of the list

Tags: drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I noticed that on the semantic-ui website, whenever you click on a multiselect dropdown list and then you click out of it, it selects the element that is highlighted even if you don't click on it.

The example is at: http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#tagging-and-user-additions

If you click on the dropdown (the one with the title that says **Multilpe**) and then out of it, it selects 'Angular' as option.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is already fixed on Semantic-UI `2.2.8`/`2.2.9`.

I found this bug on my company project and I was able to avoid this behavior by  setting `forceSelection` to `false`.

More clearly modifyng this behavior for the dropdown component itself with:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({forceSelection: false});
```

Or globally with

```
$.fn.dropdown.settings.forceSelection = false;
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the forceSelection didn't work but upgrading the version did!